# Pointer array and sizeof confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does the following code output **4**?

```
char** pointer = new char*[1];
std::cout << sizeof(pointer) << "\n";
```

I have an array of pointers, but it should have length 1, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why do you think you need a `char**`? In C++, we prefer the type `std::vector<std::string>`. Then you can simply call `.size()` and get the desired result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`pointer` is a pointer.  It is the size of a pointer, which is 4 bytes on your system.

`*pointer` is also a pointer. `sizeof(*pointer)` will also be 4.

`**pointer` is a char. `sizeof(**pointer)` will be 1.  Note that **pointer is a char because it is defined as `char**`.  The size of the array new`ed nevers enters into this.

Note that `sizeof` is a compiler operator.  It is rendered to a constant at compile time.  Anything that could be changed at runtime (like the size of a new'ed array) cannnot be determined using `sizeof`.

Note 2:  If you had defined that as:

```
char* array[1];
char** pointer = array;
```

Now `pointer` has essencially the same value as before, but now you can say:

```
 int  arraySize = sizeof(array); // size of total space of array 
 int  arrayLen = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); // number of element == 1 here.
```

Comment: How to determine the size of an array at runtime? Only by keeping track of what length I created it with?

Comment: Pretty much, that's it.  Youhave to remember what size you new'ed it to.  Note that the run-time library must also store that info somewhere (so it know how many destructors to run), but that not made accessible.

Comment: Yes, or use `std::vector< >`. It has a `size` method.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` always returns a number of bytes.

Here, `pointer` is an ... err ... pointer and is 32 bits on 32 bits architectures, i.e. 4 bytes.

Comment: and 8 bytes on a 64bit system, but only when you compile in 64bit mode

Answer (score 3):

When you call sizeof you're asking for how large it is in terms of bytes. 
A pointer is actually an integer that represents an address where the data you're pointing to is, and assuming that you're using a x32 operating system the size of an int is 4 bytes.

Comment: actually, the pointer is a pointer. It usually corresponds to the machine word, but I wouldn't call it an int, that's mixing concepts.

Comment: Ooh, think I had this problem once before. So I divide sizeof(..) by 4. Thx.

Comment: @a1337q; the sizeof of a pointer will (most likely) always be 4 on a 32-bit archtitecture, you can't use it to determine the size of an array, no matter how you try.

Comment: It's an integer, but not necessarily an `int` (although pointers are frequently the same size as ints, as both are usually the size of the CPU's internal registers)

Comment: @a1337q: No, you don't divide by 4.

Comment: @Bill: I'll use this: sizeof(pointer)/sizeof(char*). But dividing by 4 would also work if I run the code only on my computer.

Comment: Pointers certainly weren't integers back when C was designed. Just look at the 8086, where pointers were a pair of integers.

Comment: @a1337: does it work if you declare an array of size 2?  (Hint: No. http://codepad.org/PhVM6bGo)

Answer (score 2):

`pointer` is of type `char**`, whic has size of 4

what you might want is `char * pointer [1]`

but to have the length of such array you need the following code

`int len = sizeof(pointer)/sizeof(char*)`

check this out:

```
int * pArr = new int[5];
int Arr[5];

sizeof(pArr); //==4 for 32 bit arch
sizeof(Arr); //==20 for 32 bit arch
sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(int); //==5 for any arch
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the size of "pArr" ?

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` does not give you the size of dynamic arrays (whose size is only determined at **run-time**, and could be of different size during different executions).

`sizeof` is always evaluated at **compile-time** and it gives you the size of the type in question, in this case the type is `char**` - a pointer (to pointer).

It is your task to keep track of the size of dynamically allocated arrays (you know how much you requested in the first place). Since it is a burden, all the more reason to use containers and the string class, which keep track of the allocation size themselves.