# Memory Usage estimation

Tags: c++

I am wondered about the memory usage of variables and I tried this :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* testChar1 = "Hi";
    char* testChar2 = "This is a test variable";
    char* testChar3 = "";

    std::cout <<sizeof(testChar1)<<std::endl; 
    std::cout <<sizeof (testChar2) <<std::endl; 
    std::cout <<sizeof(testChar3)<<std::endl;
}
```

output is :

```
4
4
4
```

I think I am not doing the right thing. I want to know how much memory every variable uses in stack .

**EDIT 1**

At the same time if I does `char* testChar3 = NULL`; the program crashes. So does it mean there is no memory usage for the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array) or perhaps [Pointer array and sizeof confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397098/pointer-array-and-sizeof-confusion)

Comment: Setting `char* testChar3 = NULL` and then "reading"/accessing it later while it is still `null` will result in a null pointer exception - which is why your program crashes.

Comment: ok, so is this variable will be gone out from stack when set to NULL?

Comment: No, well, kinda. What you have there is a `char` pointer. If you set the `char*` (`char` pointer) to null then you have still have a `char*`; it just does not point to anything.

Comment: Also, the reason you are seeing `4` when you are printing out the size of the pointers is because a pointer consists of 32-bits (4 bytes) for 32-bit executables.

Comment: Where exactly your programm crash?

Answer (score 2):

You simply print the size of the pointers, they always will be the same. What you need is to multiply `strlen` for the strings by the size of a single char.

EDIT: as per my comment and the correction from @Suma:

```
cout << (strlen(testChar) + 1) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(testChar);
```

The 1 is needed for the terminating zero character.

Comment: Is that is same count which the stack or heap uses on execution
?

Comment: Plus constant additional memory for each string, in this case for the pointer.

Comment: so Am i supposed to do `strlen(testChar)*sizeof(testChar)`? and the term `constant additional memory for each string` refers to?

Comment: @ACB no. You should do `strlen(testChar)*sizeof(char) + sizeof(testChar)`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Do not forget the terminating zero.

Comment: @Suma right, forgot about it of course.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is a verbose way to write `1`, and `x * 1` is a no-op

Comment: @MSalters it makes it easier to understand the code. Otherwise I will need to explain that it is always 1 and that I omitted this one because it is not needed.

Comment: And what if the strings (literal) overlaps? :-)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `strlen`, you could also use `sizeof` on a

```
char testChar1[] = "Hi";
```

EDIT: yes, this includes the null terminator, which IMO is an advantage over `strlen`. The actual size does include the null terminator.

Comment: @ACB Note that this includes the null terminated character.

Comment: why not `char const wtf[]= "hi";` ?

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(testChar1)` return size of pointer, if you want to test string length try replace `sizeof` with `strlen`

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you're only printing the size of the pointers and not the chars. So really, you would want to print the pointer, then dereference it and print the size of the memory it points to as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually printing the amonut of bytes a pointer takes on your system . I think what you need to do is to use strlen function . Check it out here . [strlen](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html)

```
std::cout<<strlen(testChar1)<<std::endl;
std::cout <<strlen(testChar2) <<std::endl; 
std::cout <<strlen(testChar3)<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to know how much memory every variable uses in stack .
```

What your programm print is exactly what you want.

Read the other answer if what you really want is to know how much memory (where??!!) occupy the char-strings pointed by yours variables - pointers.