# Why is this sizeof operator giving error?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In this program, the line `int len = sizeof(*a)/sizeof(int);` gives the error, however if I write this `int len = sizeof(**a)/sizeof(int);` or this `int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);`, it works fine. Why is that? Here `a` holds the address of 1-D array and when I do this, `*a`, it gives the address of first element of the array and finally `**a` gives the element itself. So based on this the line `int len = sizeof(*a)/sizeof(int);` should work fine, isn't it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int (*a)[]){
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(int));
    int len = sizeof(*a)/sizeof(int);  // error
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        printf("%d ", (*a)[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6}
    };
    func(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*a` is an array of indeterminate size; what answer is `sizeof()` supposed to give?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no matter how you specify func's arguments, you won't ever get the actual C array in your func function, most likely a pointer that tries to look like an array

Use std::array or pass the length of the array as a second argument

Comment: @jonathan, It should give the size of pointer variable, isn't it? Just like when we do sizeof(a).

Comment: No; it shouldn't.  It should give the size of the object which is `*a`, and that is an array of unknown size, so `sizeof(*a)` cannot give an answer, so the compilation (correctly) fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer array and sizeof confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397098/pointer-array-and-sizeof-confusion)

Comment: @ksone: your possible duplicate is only very loosely related.  I don't think it is a good duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter a is a pointer to an incomplete type. You cannot use sizeof on it since it is a pointer to an array and the size of the array isn't defined.

You can define it:

```
void func(int (*a)[10]){
```

In this case `sizeof(*a)` will equal to `sizeof( int )*10` and `sizeof(*a)/sizeof(int);` will give the element count of a, which is 10 in this case.

Since you are passing a pointer to an array of size 3 you should use 3 not 10.
You can use forward parameters to have a variable sized argument `a`.

Answer (score 6):

Standard says:

#### C11: 6.5.3.4

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an **incomplete type** [..]

**An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type** (C11: 6.2.5 Types--p22). `*a` in `func` is of incomplete type. You need to specify the length of the array `a` points to before using it as an operand of `sizeof`.