# Array of vector

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector, row

I am using an array of vectors. I have to count number of rows in the array. I am using the technique used for a 2D array. But it does not give desired output.

```
int main()
{    
    int i,p=7;
    vector<float> *mat=new vector<float>[p];
    int k=5;
    for(i=0;i<p;i++){
        mat[i].assign(k,0);
    }
    cout<<sizeof(mat)/sizeof(mat[0])<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Why is this resulting in 0 ? Shouldn't the output be 7?
How to calculate number of rows ?

Comment: First of all, `sizeof(mat)` give you the size of the *pointer*, not the size of whatever memory it point so. Secondly, `sizeof(mat[0])` give you the size of the `std::vector` object itself, not the number of elements in the vector (that would be e.g. `mat[0].length()`). And why don't you use a vector of vectors (i.e. `vector<vector<float>>`) instead (or if `k` is a compile-time constant, a vector of arrays, as in `vector<array<float, 5>>`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer array and sizeof confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397098/pointer-array-and-sizeof-confusion)

Comment: @remi `sizeof` is a computed at compile time, you can't do `mat[0].length()`

Comment: @Tyker Ah, right. Will remove that comment, thanks.

Comment: @Tyker I guess it was .size() I meant. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @remi it wouldn't work either, the issue is that the length of a vector is variable at run time and sizeof is calculated a compile time

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , vector of vectors is giving segmentation fault. The number of rows ~20000. That's why I'm trying to use dynamic memory allocation by using array of vectors. However, number of columns is ~50.

Comment: But `std::vector` *use* "dynamic allocation" behind the scene. You should be able to have `std::vector<std:vector<float>> mat(50, std::vector<float>(20000));` without problems, unless you're on a very limited and memory constrained system. Or with your variables, `std::vector<std::vector<float>> mat(p, std::vector<float>(k));`.

Comment: off-topic, but your `mat` is leaking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and a file with 10000 rows and 50 columns is giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: Then please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially catch the crash in a debugger to locate when and where it happens in your code. And if you can't solve it on your own, then please ask a new question about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, upto 6000 rows the code is working fine, after that segmentation fault occurs.